# Clicks on the screen while laptop lid is closed

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management, laptop

I just installed a new distribution of Ubuntu 16.04 and have been configuring it, but something has been happening when the laptop lid is closed. After I close the lid for, say, 30 minutes, I will be left with a wide variety of programs opened on my screen (Typically the LibreOffice tools, about 5 file folders, my windows partition folder, and firefox).

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMcxx.png)

My screen wasn't hibernating when I closed the lid (which didn't happen on my previous 14.04 installation), so I modified the /etc/systemd/logind.conf file to set `HandleLidSwitch=hibernate`.

This set the laptop screen to hibernate and lock my user properly when I closed the lid, but the problem still persisted. The clicks would just go into the guest user and do the same thing.

Some additional info:

My laptop is an HP Pavilion 360 (which has a touchscreen, could be significant?).

I have a wireless mouse plugged connected to the computer via a dongle, but the problem persists whether or not the wireless mouse is within range of the computer.

[My power settings are currently configured like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzPi3.png)

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

From freedesktop.org's description of the logind.conf file:

> A different application may disable logind's handling of system power and sleep keys and the lid switch by taking a low-level inhibitor lock ("handle-power-key", "handle-suspend-key", "handle-hibernate-key", "handle-lid-switch"). This is most commonly used by graphical desktop environments to take over suspend and hibernation handling, and to use their own configuration mechanisms. If a low-level inhibitor lock is taken, logind will not take any action when that key or switch is triggered and the Handle*= settings are irrelevant.

I assume that this means the Power Settings will take precedence over any changes that I make to the logind.conf file. Is there any way to override/customize these power settings other than through the settings interface?

Comment: Just to be safe set `HandleLidSwitchDocked=hibernate` as well.

Comment: I have the same problem with my HP Pavilion with Ubuntu 18.04. Not touchscreen so I think we can exclude that.

Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the touchpad solved it for me. If you or someone else have the same problem, try installing touchpad-indicator and disable the touchpad while the lid is closed.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```